# Does gem5 have clflush implemented?

Tags: gem5

I would like to use clflush in gem5. Does gem5 have clflush implemented?

I saw a warning saying instruction 'wbinvd' unimplemented.

Comment: Why don't you give it a try and see what happens? :-) A quick git grep seems to indicate it is implemented.

Comment: @CiroSantilli: Thanks for your reply, have a great day